# Add free product to cart woocommerce but only on certain dates

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a shop and we would like our customers get a free product. I found a code that is working fine. BUT is there a way to run the code only on certain dates? We have a celebration week ahead of us and the promotion should be available on Monday and Tuesday and Thursday till Sunday.

```
function aapc_add_product_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;
    
    $cart_total = 50;   

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->total >= $cart_total ) {
        if ( ! is_admin() ) {
            $free_product_id = 272877;  // Product Id of the free product which will get added to cart
            $found      = false;

            //check if product already in cart
            if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
                foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                    $_product = $values['data'];
                    if ( $_product->get_id() == $free_product_id )
                        $found = true;                  
                }
                // if product not found, add it
                if ( ! $found )
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
            } else {
                // if no products in cart, add it
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
            }        
        }
    }        
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'aapc_add_product_to_cart' );


function remove_free_product_from_cart() {

// Run only in the Cart or Checkout Page
if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {

$prod_to_remove = 272877; // Product ID of Free Product

$no_any_product_check = false;

$cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

if ( sizeof( $cart ) == 1 ) {

// Check in the cart if any other product is present or not

foreach ( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $prod_in_cart ) {
// Get the Variation or Product ID
$prod_id = ( isset( $prod_in_cart['variation_id'] ) && $prod_in_cart['variation_id'] != 0 ) ? $prod_in_cart['variation_id'] : $prod_in_cart['product_id'];

if ( $prod_to_remove == $prod_id ) {
$free_pro_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $prod_id );
$no_any_product_check = true;
}
}
// If any product is not present then remove the free product.
if ( $no_any_product_check ) {
unset( WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $free_pro_cart_id ] );
}

}
}
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'remove_free_product_from_cart' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following right at the top of your two functions:

`if ( !in_array( date('N'), array( 1,2,4,5,6,7 ) ) ) return;`

This will stop your hooks from executing any further if the current day of the week (represented numerically from 1-7) is not in the specified array.

So you can set for which days of the week you want your code to run (1 = Monday, 7 = Sunday). The above example will let your code run on Monday and Tuesday and Thursday till Sunday.

You could also simply just check for Wednesday in your case:

`if ( date('N') == 3 ) return;`

But I thought you maybe want to use this later on and specify other weekdays on which your code should run.